# Error in SQL statement: NoClassDefFoundError: com/macasaet/fernet/Validator

Tags: java, scala, jar, databricks, fernet

Currently working on converting below code as "JAR" to register permanent UDF in Databricks cluster. facing issue like NoClassDefFoundError, But i added required Library dependencies while building Jar using SBT. source code : https://databricks.com/notebooks/enforcing-column-level-encryption.html

Used Below in build.sbt

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "0.13.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.macasaet.fernet" % "fernet-java8" % "1.5.0"

Guide me on right libraries if anything wrong above.

Kindly help me on this,

```
import com.macasaet.fernet.{Key, StringValidator, Token}
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

class Validator extends StringValidator {

  override def getTimeToLive() : java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount = {
    Duration.ofSeconds(Instant.MAX.getEpochSecond());
  }
}

class udfDecrypt extends UDF {

  def evaluate(inputVal: String, sparkKey : String): String = {

    if( inputVal != null && inputVal!="" ) {
      val keys: Key = new Key(sparkKey)
      val token = Token.fromString(inputVal)
      val validator = new Validator() {}
      val payload = token.validateAndDecrypt(keys, validator)
      payload
    } else return inputVal
  }
}
```

Comment: You need either do `sbt assembly` to include this dependency into jar, or add this dependency explicitly to the cluster definition

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexOtt! fixed it!.  While reading Secret from Spark config getting below error, any thoughts?

HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String udfDecrypt.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) with arguments {***gAAAAABf4kVBzP-LI0geSu0hlXq89XwAgxeJ4QZAbYhnj5MobaO9KZxtxsP8XRZ1O6LskZwdI8hr5QH9gtGXYffSaKDwQjLNiQ==,[REDACTED]}:Illegal base64 character 2a
Caused by: InvocationTargetException: 
Caused by: IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2a

Comment: check that your string is valid base64

Comment: Sure, Thanks!, let me check!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the fernet-java library is installed in your cluster.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This topic is related to

[Databricks SCALA UDF cannot load class when registering function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70335768/databricks-scala-udf-cannot-load-class-when-registering-function/)

I tried more to install the jar file to the cluster via the Libraries in the config, not drop directly to DBFS as the userguide, then I faced the issue with validator not found and the question routed me here.

I added the maven repo to the Libraries config, but then the cluster failed to installed it, with error

```
Library resolution failed because unresolved dependency: com.macasaet.fernet:fernet-java8:1.5.0: not found
```

[databricks cluster libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QofVw.png)

Have you experienced with this?

Comment: Finally, the 'sbt assemly' for a uber jar file could help.