# Databricks SCALA UDF cannot load class when registering function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have followed [this guide](https://databricks.com/notebooks/enforcing-column-level-encryption.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964275/creating-user-defined-not-temporary-function-in-spark-sql-for-azure-databricks) trying to implement a decryption function to use in a SQL view.

I have compiled this scala code in the example to a jar file and uploaded to the Databricks File System (DBFS):

```scala
import com.macasaet.fernet.{Key, StringValidator, Token};
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import java.time.{Duration, Instant};

class Validator extends StringValidator {
    override def getTimeToLive() : java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount = {
      Duration.ofSeconds(Instant.MAX.getEpochSecond());
    }
  }

class udfDecrypt extends UDF {

    def evaluate(inputVal: String, sparkKey : String): String = {

      if( inputVal != null && inputVal!="" ) {
        val keys: Key = new Key(sparkKey)
        val token = Token.fromString(inputVal)
        val validator = new Validator() {}
        val payload = token.validateAndDecrypt(keys, validator)
        payload
      } else return inputVal
    }
  }
```

I can declare the function as demonstrated:

```sql
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION default.udfDecrypt AS 'com.nm.udf.udfDecrypt'
USING jar 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/decryptUDF.jar';
```

But if I try to call it an error is thrown:

```sql
%sql
SELECT default.udfDecrypt(field, '{key}') FROM default.encrypted_test;
```

`Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Can not load class 'com.nm.udf.udfDecrypt' when registering the function 'default.udfDecrypt', please make sure it is on the classpath; line 1 pos 7`

I have noticed that the function can be declared using any jar file path (even one that doesn't exist) and it will still return 'OK'.

I am using Databricks for Azure.

Comment: Can you validate the jar exists at the dbfs path?

Comment: Yes, just rechecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your UDF code is missing:

```
package com.nm.udf;
```

at the top.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update as of 2022 October, because the accepted solution did not work for me.

First off, the given Scala code is incorrect, **you need to add**...

```
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.Instant;
```

To the top of the code.

Secondly, after packing the `.scala` file to `jar` (using `sbt package` for example...), when you create the function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udfDecryptor AS 'udfDecrypt'
USING jar 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/decryptUDF.jar';
```

Then the alias of the function **must match** the name of the class.

Pay attention to having the `build.sbt` file with the correct version and dependencies, for example...

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.2.0-properscala"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.14"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "the_name_of_project_here"
  )

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library
libraryDependencies += "com.macasaet.fernet" % "fernet-java8" % "1.5.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "3.1.2"
```

This is the only way I managed to solve it and made running of the code successful. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some hidden parts in the guidlines.
Here is a complete repo to make things in details.

https://github.com/dungruoc/databricks-fernet-udf

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing supporting source code/summary/steps from link to solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).